# is it possible to extract "Description" of an ecoinvent activity?

Tags: brightway

I'm trying to automate the extraction of the "Description" of activities from ecoinvent database (e.g., "wood preservation facility construction, dipping/immersion tank | wood preservation facility, dipping/immersion tank"), using brightway2.

As there seems no such an attribute called "description" in the activity object, I tried "comment" instead. I was expecting the following content from the activity named "wood preservation facility construction, dipping/immersion tank | wood preservation facility, dipping/immersion tank":
"*The dipping or immersion tank consists of the main steel tank containing the preservative and an second, larger steel tank as the retention tank, within which the first tank is located. As an alternative design the main tank can be placed in a sealed concrete construction, serving as the retention tank. Appart from the tanks, a lifting device (for lifting the wood into and out of the tank) as well as a hold-down device (to ensure complete immersion) are inventoried.;The length of the inventoried tank is 12 m, corresponding to a medium sized tank, The batch size is between 12 - 16 m3 of wood. Assuming an average input of 9 l of preservative/m3 , a yearly throughput of 6000 m3 of wood and a service life of 75 years, about 4.05E06 kg of wood preservative are applied over the service life of the tank.;;Data on land use and on the building hall are taken from pressure vessel processes as no specific data on these infrastructure inputs could be gathered. These values refer to a yearly throughput of 6000 m3 of wood.; Infrastructure dataset containing the main elements of the facility. The land area and the material (production and disposal) needed for a preservative treatment plant for dipping or immersion treatment including strorage area is included. 60 - 90 kg of 2-component laquers are not inventoried.*" The content is presented in the "Description" field under "General Information" section, if you open the activity in OpenLCA software.

But what was returned was the following:
"*Data from Germany and Switzerland. Location of plant within Europe of minor importance*" (which is the content of another "Description" field under "Geography" section, if you open the activity in OpenLCA software).

**Is there any way I can retrive the correct Description content of an activity using bw2? Thanks**